# Do two elements in the same homology class have the same homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Do two elements in the same homology class have the same homology?

Specifically, let's say we have a topological space $X$ and two singular $n$-cycles which are also generators of the chain group of $X$, i.e. $\sigma_1, \sigma_2: \Delta_n \to X$ continuous and $\sigma_1, \sigma_2 \in Z_n(X)$.

Now assume that it is true that $[\sigma_1]=[\sigma_2] \in H_n(X)$; then is it the case that all of the homology groups of $\sigma_1(X)$ are equal to those of $\sigma_2(X)$ (when $\sigma_1(\Delta_n) \subseteq X$ and $\sigma_2(\Delta_n) \subseteq X$ have the subspace topology)?

I think the answer is no, because the zeroth and first homologies of $S^1$ and $S^1 \sqcup S^1$ are different, since for the first $H_0(S^1)=H_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$ and for the second $H_0(S^1 \sqcup S^1)=H_1(S^1 \sqcup S^1) = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$, but when their embeddings in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are considered as 1-cycles, I think that they might be homologous (as $1-$cycles in $Z_1(\mathbb{R}^3)$) because there is a cobordism between them, thus their oriented difference should be a boundary.

See Figure 1 [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266748006_Computing_Minimum_Area_Homologies/figures). This question is basically about the pair of pants cobordism. See also [my previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255096/are-cobordism-and-singular-homology-equivalent-for-smooth-manifolds-why-or-why) on MathOverflow.

Comment: How do you define "$\sigma(X)$" (recalling that $\sigma$ is a map from $\Delta^n$ *to* $X$)? Do you mean the image of $\sigma$? (Also, cobordisms are pretty irrelevant here.)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Sorry for the typo. Also, would you mind explaining how cobordisms are "pretty irrelevant here"?

Comment: Well being homologous is much more general than being cobordant (it's not even trivial that cobordant submanifolds will have homologous fundamental classes in the ambient manifold by the way), and if you have a random singular $1$-simplex its image is not guaranteed to be a manifold. Besides $H_1(\mathbb{R}^3) = 0$... Any $1$-cycle in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is homologous to any other one.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi This is all true. However, unlike an arbitrary singular $1$-simplex, 1-manifolds are actually easy to visualize. Anyway, how is being homologous much more general than being cobordant for manifolds which are also singular n-cycles? The choice of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is largely immaterial, it's just so that both the manifolds I am asking about as well as their cobordism can be embedded into the space.

Comment: If you have two disjoint compact oriented submanifolds $M, M' \subset N$ and an embedded cobordism $W \subset N$ between $M$ and $M'$, then the pushforwards of the fundamental classes $[M]$ and $[M']$ will be homologous in $H_n(N)$, because manifolds can be triangulated.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi OK, I think I finally get it now. I was just trying to use the idea of cobordism to gain some visual intuition for homology. The fact that manifolds can be triangulated implies that we can reduce the question to simplicial homology, for which a "simplicial cobordism" between two $n-$cycles obviously means that they are in the same homology class? And this is related to all (smooth) manifolds being homotopy equivalent to CW complexes and thus singular and simplicial homology always being equivalent for them since both homology theories satisfy the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms?

Comment: It's simpler than that, actually. Then the fundamental class $[W] \in H_n(W, \partial W)$ gives a chain in $C_{n+1}(N)$ whose differential is, basically by definition, $d[W] = [M'] - [M]$ (and actually you don't need triangulations I think, I made a mistake).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A circle and figure eight in the plane are both images of 1-cycles (homologous since $H_1(\mathbb{R}^2)=0$), but have different $H_1$.